# subnetting to give 4 2000 adresses

Tags: subnet, ip-address, networking

A large number of consecutive IP addresses are available starting at 198.16.0.0/19. Suppose that four organizations, A, B, C, and D, request 2000, 2000, 2000, and 2000 addresses, respectively, and in that order. For each of these, give the first IP address assigned, the last IP address assigned, and the mask in the w.x.y.z/s notation

Comment: i saw a lot of answers to a similar questions but i still didn't get it

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all.